# Setting sas date to yymmdd8 as a character variable

Tags: datetime, sas

Putting on my dunce cap because I'm sure the answer will be simple but for the life if me I can't get this to work. I need to convert the numeric date to display as follows "20200412" to try and match between another data set.

I've tried this:
Newdate=put (old date, yymmdd8.); and it just makes new date display as blank.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `old date` is not a valid variable name.  You want the `YYMMDDN` format, not the `YYMMDD` format. Otherwise you get hyphens in the text.  Is the current variable numeric or character? Does it have a format attached?  If so what format?  Does the target variable `newdate` already exist? What is its type? If character what max length does it allow?

Comment: Forgot the underscore on the variable for the example but adding in n to the format fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use **newDate=input(oldDate, YYMMDDN.);** instead.

```
data test;
    oldDate="20220412";
    format newDate YYMMDDN.;
    newDate=input(oldDate, YYMMDDN.);
run;
```

This format is what you want.